# How is the performance hit of change locale in Laravel

Tags: php, performance, laravel

I am trying to use Laravel localization class to generate emails in both French and English base on our clients' preference and their friends', and we are having a debate on the performance cost of dynamically changing the locality by calling setLocale for each person every time we are trying to generate email template , does any one have an idea here ? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the performance isn't heavily affected as `setLocale` only changes the path your language strings are loaded from, they have to be loaded either way if you're using the translation files.

Comment: Thank you... that was what I was thinking